# MySql Case statement to get first row where datetime is after now

Tags: mysql, datetime, case

I have a query which currently highlights the current appointment as "NOW" and all subsequent appointments as "NEXT". I am having trouble adapting this though to show only one appointment as being the next one.

Here's what I have so far...

```
SELECT 
    user_name,
    DATE(apt_start_datetime) AS apt_date, 
    TIME(apt_start_datetime) AS apt_start_time,  
    TIME(apt_end_datetime) AS apt_end_time,
    CASE 
        WHEN (NOW() BETWEEN apt_start_datetime AND apt_end_datetime) THEN 'NOW' 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN (NOW() < apt_start_datetime) THEN 'NEXT' ELSE NULL END 
        END AS now_next
FROM 
    users 
JOIN 
    apts ON DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%x%v") = DATE_FORMAT(apt_start_datetime, "%x%v")
WHERE 
    user_id = 123456
ORDER BY 
    apt_date, 
    apt_start_time
```

This returns something like:

```
user_name     apt_date       apt_start_time      apt_end_time     now_next
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
user1         2015-11-20     10:45:00            10:55:00         null
user2         2015-11-20     10:55:00            11:55:00         NOW
user3         2015-11-20     11:55:00            12:15:00         NEXT
user4         2015-11-20     12:15:00            12:35:00         NEXT
user5         2015-11-20     12:35:00            12:55:00         NEXT
```

But what I want is this:

```
user_name     apt_date       apt_start_time      apt_end_time     now_next
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
user1         2015-11-20     10:45:00            10:55:00         null
user2         2015-11-20     10:55:00            11:55:00         NOW
user3         2015-11-20     11:55:00            12:15:00         NEXT
user4         2015-11-20     12:15:00            12:35:00         null
user5         2015-11-20     12:35:00            12:55:00         null
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try a nested select that you would limit to 1 for the 'NEXT'. But that wouldn't be very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is causing this part of sql

```
CASE WHEN (NOW() < apt_start_datetime) THEN 'NEXT' ELSE NULL END
```

All rows where apt_start_datetime is earlier than NOW() will have "NEXT".

You have to find **first** apt_start_datetime which is later then NOW() and this datetime use for comparision instead of apt_start_datetime.

In pseudo sql something like

```
CASE WHEN (NOW() < (SELECT apt_start_datetime FROM tbl WHERE apt_start_datetime > NOW() ORDER BY DIFF(apt_start_datetime,NOW()) DESC  LIMIT 1)) THEN 'NEXT' ELSE NULL END
```

EDIT: this is easiest solution, but will be pretty slow

Comment: I get the following error: FUNCTION xyz.DIFF does not exist

Comment: use TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, apt_start_datetime,  NOW())